# How to print normalized data in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a data normalized using `normalizr`:

```
{
  result: "123",
  entities: {
    "articles": { 
      "123": { 
        id: "123",
        author: "1",
        title: "My awesome blog post",
        comments: [ "324" ]
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "1": { "id": "1", "name": "Paul" },
      "2": { "id": "2", "name": "Nicole" }
    },
    "comments": {
      "324": { id: "324", "commenter": "2" }
    }
  }
}
```

I save `entities` in reducer and I want to print them on my page.
I can do that like this:

```
const articles = data.entities.articles;
for (let key in articles) {
  console.log( articles[key].author + ', ' +  articles[key].title);
}
```

Is that ok in React/Redux print normalized data in JSX template like this or there is exist a better way?

**UPD**

I create an application using this example https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world but I don't understand how there a data from `entities` printed in JSX templates.

I am confused about a data structure because usually I used arrays but in `real-world` example a new for me way, where data normalized like this.

Comment: What you mean by printing them on your page? In your JSX template? or just console log?

Comment: Hi! in JSX template

Comment: Reducers should be used to prepare data to save in your state. Grabbing the data you want from the state should happen in the views only.

Comment: You need a container connect your reducer states with your component. Then in your component,
this.props.data.entities.articles.map(function(item, i){
  console.log('test');
  return <li>Test</li>
})

Comment: @tywoodpav yes, I prepare a data using `normalizr` and save a data in reducer. After that I want to print this data from reducer

Comment: @MaduraPradeep but `articles` in not an array, I can't use `.map` on `articles`, can I?

Comment: If you want to print this in your view (JSX template), you can use something like I commented and you need a container for that. You can't do it in reducer. 
If you want to just console print, what you did is right.

Comment: Your reducer should supply a state like { articles:[], users:[], comments:[]} (might make sense to have in separate reducers) and then you pass them to views (which render JSX templates) like @Madura said

Comment: @MaduraPradeep I have a container. And in my container I pass `articles` which is an `object`.

Comment: If it is an object, you can do something like below.

this.props.data.entities.articles.keys().map(function(key, i){ 
let data=this.props.data.entities.articles[key];
console.log('test'); return <li>Test</li> })

Comment: Seems like your confused about your data structures then. If it makes sense to have articles as an object, convert it to one either in the reducer or in your source. If it makes sense to have it as an array, do that instead. JSX happens in the view. I don't know where you're lost.

Comment: @tywoodpav yep, I updated my post can you take another one look on it, please?

Comment: Look up how to loop through an object.

Comment: My answer did not solve your problem?

Comment: @MaduraPradeep yep, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect your reducer with your view, you need a container. Then in your view, you can do something like in following jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/madura/g50ocwh2/

```
      var data = {
    result: "123",
    entities: {
      "articles": {
        "123": {
          id: "123",
          author: "1",
          title: "My awesome blog post",
          comments: ["324"]
        }
      },
      "users": {
        "1": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Paul"
        },
        "2": {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Nicole"
        }
      },
      "comments": {
        "324": {
          id: "324",
          "commenter": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  };

  console.log(data.entities.articles);
  return ( < div > {
    Object.keys(data.entities.articles).map(function(key) {
      return <p key = {
        key
      } > {
        data.entities.articles[key].title
      } < /p>
    })
  } < /div>);
}
```

You will get your data as a property to your view after you connect with container. So you can access your data like below in your view.

```
this.props.data.entities.articles;
```